# Maven scm update

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, maven-scm

I am new to **Maven** world, so help me out please. 
I have a normal **Maven project** that uses *SVN* for version control.
What i want to do is have Maven automatically fetch some scripts from a *SVN* folder and place them inside the project.This should be done when i order maven to build the application **WAR** file. Here is the catch: the folder i want to pick up from *SVN* is not on the same *SVN* folder as the current project. It is on a different *SVN* folder. Ex.: httxx://svnprd/svn/project/here and httxx://svnprd/svn/scripts/here

I have read about the **scm plugin**, but i have not been able to set it up correctly, or to find a decent tutorial on it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) be of any use to you?

Comment: @Jiri, spent some time reading about it, but no, is not what i wanted. I did menage to get it working tough... i was trying to use scm:update on a second project, and that doesn't work, but using scm:export solved my problem. thanks for your time man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was my own mistake, i was trying to use scm:update instead of scm:export. thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

[Antrun plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) could help you. Hook it in `generate-sources` phase and write ant script that checks out the SVN folder and moves the files where needed.

Comment: Thanks @Jiri , but i can only use the Antrun plugin if and only if i find no way around without using it. boss orders, xD

Comment: Sure, hopefully someone will be able to provide a cleaner way. Antrun is kind of "I give up" last resort :)